# In NaiveUI, how to make responsable container

Tags: vuejs3, naiveui

If I use naive ui, how make a responsive container?

I've been using ant design vue so far.
In PC, I created a responsive container like this using Ant Design Vue.

```
<a-row type="flex" justify="center">
          <a-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :md="22" :lg="20" :xl="16" :xxl="14">
              ...
          </a-col>
</a-row>
```

How to create a responsive container when using a naive UI?
(Naive UI : https://www.naiveui.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should use Naive UI's
[Responsive columns](https://www.naiveui.com/en-US/os-theme/components/grid#responsive.vue) and [Responsive grid item](https://www.naiveui.com/en-US/os-theme/components/grid#responsive-item.vue).